# d3js mousemove event is not bubbling

Tags: javascript, events, d3.js, event-bubbling

I have an svg structure similar to the following:

```
<svg>
   <g id="main-group">
     ...
      <rect id="event-rect"></rect>
   </g>
</svg>
```

and i have attached the same events to the #event-rect and #main-group

```
 d3.select('#event-rect').on('mousemove', clb);
 d3.select('#main-group').on('mousemove', clb2);
```

The problem here is that the first clb is triggered whereas the event listener of the parent node (i.e. #main-group) is not.

Why doesn't the event bubbling phase working here?

The actual code that use is:

```
 d3.select('#event-rect').on('mousedown', mousedown);
 d3.select('#event-rect').on('mousemove', mousemove);
 d3.select('#event-rect').on('mouseup', mouseup);
```

Then in another module i attach the same set of the events:

```
 d3.select('#main-group').on('mousedown', dragStart);
 d3.select('#main-group').on('mousemove', mousemove);
 d3.select('#main-group').on('mouseup', dragEnd);
```

All the callbacks are invoked except for the dragStart. I doesn't make any sense to me whatsoever

Answer (score 2):

If the dimensions of the elements are identical, the `g` element will be obscured by the `rect`. Depending on what you want to do, there are a couple of options.

- You could increase the size of the `g` element such that the event is triggered when the mouse just leaves the `rect`.
- You could remove the listener for the `g` element altogether and execute its actions in the handler for the `rect`.
- Similarly, you could remove the listener from the `rect` element and handle everything in the listener for the `g` element.

Comment: yes, but how about event bubbling. Shouldn't the mousemove event promoted to its parent nodes? I think that's how the ordinary dom elements act

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I misunderstood your question. This works fine for me -- can you post the complete code please?

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake. I have a problem with the 'mousedown' event. The mousemove event does bubble for me, as well.

Comment: Are you sure that the mousedown works fine. I had a look at the source code and i've notices that d3js calls the d3_eventCancel() methods which in turn calls d3.event.stopPropagation();

Comment: cheers for the help. The problem was in the version of the library that i was using

Comment: You're welcome. I suggest deleting the question though to avoid confusing people who search for similar things.